Why is my water wave animated footer not working in HTML CSS?
I stumbled across this water wave animated footer on YouTube and I'm currently working on a project myself so I decided to implement the footer into my own project. The thing is that's it's not working. The "wave" image is not showing up in the first place. I'll drop my code, the YouTube link and what the footer looks like in my project below. I'd appreciate your help, and thank you for your time!


footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dark-color);
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
footer .social-icons,
footer .menu{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
footer .social-icons li a{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
footer .social-icons li a:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
footer .menu li a{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
footer .menu li a:hover{
   opacity: 1; 
}
footer .waves .wave{
  position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TPBH3rHw/blue-waves.png);
    background-size: 1000px 100px;
}
footer .waves .wave #wave1{
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: animateWave 4s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves .wave #wave2{
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 10px;
  animation: animateWave_02 4s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves .wave #wave3{
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  bottom: 15px;
  animation: animateWave 3s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves .wave #wave4{
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0.7;
bottom: 20px;
animation: animateWave_02 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateWave{
    0%{
        background-position-x: 1000px;
    }
    100%{
        background-position-x: 0px;
    }
}
@keyframes animateWave_02{
  0%{
      background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100%{
      background-position-x: 1000px;
  }
}
<footer>
        <div class="waves">
            <div class="wave" id="wave1"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave2"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave3"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave4"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>



YouTube project link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpkEANWC2Ms&t=605s
My footer:
What my project's footer looks like
I tried changing the height and width of the "waves" class, messed around with all the values of the classes involved, copied the YouTuber's code to the dot, I relocated the image and tried it several times, nothing changed. The image still does not show up let aside animate.
Side note: The YouTuber I'm following had display: flex; on the body element, this might be the problem. Even though I tried doing the same to my body element as well, it messed up my layout but still the image did not show up.
The other problem might be the position of my waves class element but I also tried messing around with that and nothing worked.

What does looking at your browser devtools inspect facility tell you? Are there any messages on its console about images being loaded/not loaded for example? Making your code into a runnable snippet with an image we can actually get at would be helpful.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Be very careful where spaces go. e.g. in footer .waves .wave #wave1 (which is where the animation is set for the first wave) the space before the #wave1 means the system is looking for an element with id wave1 which is the child of .wave. But it is the same element, remove that space and check all the others. And is wave.png in the same folder as the css file?

When selecting wave3 you are using footer .waves .wave #wave3 you should use
footer .waves #wave3. Same thing for other waves


footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--dark-color);
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
footer .social-icons,
footer .menu{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
footer .social-icons li a{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
footer .social-icons li a:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
footer .menu li a{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
footer .menu li a:hover{
   opacity: 1; 
}
footer .waves .wave{
  position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TPBH3rHw/blue-waves.png);
    background-size: 1000px 100px;
}
footer .waves #wave1{
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: animateWave 4s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves #wave2{
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 10px;
  animation: animateWave_02 4s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves #wave3{
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  bottom: 15px;
  animation: animateWave 3s linear infinite;
}
footer .waves #wave4{
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0.7;
bottom: 20px;
animation: animateWave_02 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateWave{
    0%{
        background-position-x: 1000px;
    }
    100%{
        background-position-x: 0px;
    }
}
@keyframes animateWave_02{
  0%{
      background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100%{
      background-position-x: 1000px;
  }
}
<footer>
        <div class="waves">
            <div class="wave" id="wave1"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave2"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave3"></div>
            <div class="wave" id="wave4"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>




I fixed it, it was pretty dumb tbh lol. My css script (styles.css) was in a css folder and for some reason it wasn't fetching the image from the images file, so I moved the styles.css to the main folder and it's working now. Thank you!
